Endpoints disappearing from geometry when converting to mesh
I've been making some geometry node pipes from bezier curves and attempting to UV map them for materials. It's been going well so far, but the flanges I added as endpoints keep disappearing when I convert the geometry to mesh. I can't quite figure out why.




Got an answer! I needed to use 'Realise Instances' Nodes

It's not required that you write "got an answer" in the comments. If you have an answer, post it as an answer so that other users can see while scrolling through the questions that this problem has a solution, like my answer posted below.

They disappear because they are instances. Only "real" geometry stays after applying the modifier. You have to use a Realize Instances node to convert them.
